# Method overriding and following SOLID principles

Tags: php, overriding, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I have a parent class and a child class as follows:

```
class Request {
  public function handleException() : array {
    throw new Exception( 'RequestException' );
  }
}
```

```
class SpecialRequest extends Request {
  public function handleException() : array {
    if (condition) {
      return [];
    }
    parent::handleException();
  }
}
```

I have 2 request classes and has a handleException method that's meant to return an array. My idea is that the parent class would only throw exceptions (because it doesn't know how to handle them). While child classes would be allowed to override the parent method to handle certain cases and throw the parent exception otherwise.

Following SOLID principles, I should not change the method signatures when overriding. But looking at the parent method, it seems odd that the method has an array return type, when it's basically just throwing an exception.

Is there anything wrong with the classes?

Comment: If you declare `Request::handleException()` `abstract`, would that make this method seem less odd? You effectively force each inheriting class to implement its own handling of exception, which should be done anyway, if `Request` itself doesn't know what how to handle an exception.

Answer (score 0):

That implementation in the Request class, looks like it was supposed to throw the NotImplementedException. However this is usually a huge codesmell indicating a bad abstraction. Like if you had a toy dog and a real dog implementing the same interface, because they are both "dogs" with a method acceptBatteries. Toy dog would accept the batteries and the real dog would throw an exception. Just a bad abstraction - violation of LSP.

EDIT: If the Request class was abstract and the handle exception method was abstract.

Comment: I've updated the question, so my idea is the base class would only throw exceptions (because it doesn't know how to handle them). While child classes would be allowed to override the parent method to handle certain cases and throw the parent exception otherwise.

Comment: Then don't use superclass but rather an interface. That clearly comunicates, that method is not implemented. Check Interface Segregation Principle

Answer (score 0):

`Request::handleException()` should be declared abstract since parent class is abstract

Every leaf subclass should override it